# Setup an embedded LDAP server with spring security using Java config

Tags: spring, spring-security

I get spring security to work with a LDAP server running on my local machine, then, I move on to finish this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ (not step by step, since I am not using Spring boot)

The goal is to run spring security with an "embedded" LDAP server, but I am having trouble setting things up.

to summarize

> locally running LDAP(get it to work) vs. embedded LDAP(having trouble)

To configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder, I did

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource()
            .root("dc=oreilly,dc=com") // I didn't set url() here, so embedded server can be used
            .ldif("classpath:spring-security.ldif")
            .managerDn("uid=admin,ou=system")
            .managerPassword("secret")
            .and()
            .userSearchFilter("uid={0}");
```

in my pom.xml, I included the following libraries

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency> <!-- This is the ldap server-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I won't include other code here, since I get them to work with a local LDAP.

When I run, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/directory/server/core/partition/Partition

I think I may miss to include some libraries, but not sure which..

Answer (score 0):

After trying different setting, this works for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Also works for me, but starts an in memory instance of ApacheDS!